# Questions about the accuracy of historical movies?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should questions about the accuracy of certain incidents depicted in historical movies be asked on movies.SE, or are they better off over on history.SE? (i.e. "Did such and such really happen that way?") On the one hand they are questions about history, but on the other hand they are driven by the movie, as well as affecting what one takes from that movie.

For instance, I have a question about *Schindler's List* about a particular incident, the answer to which would either cause me to see the scene as really emotional, or eye-rolling over-the-top cheese depending on whether it occurred as portrayed. Should this be asked on Movies or History?

Comment: Refer [tag:historical-accuracy]

Comment: @AnkitSharma - Oh, looks like that's the answer!

Comment: I believe that I asked this same question in chat when I was new here.  I was told to ask on History.SE.  I asked on History.SE and they told me to ask here on movies.  lol.

Comment: should we take this question as one asking whether that tag is on–topic, or what?  maybe you could answer your own question with your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

In response to can-ned_food's comment, I thought I'd post my thoughts on the subject.

In many cases, it's the movie that inspires the question, and the truth of the matter can actually affect the enjoyment / appreciation of the movie, e.g. my own particular question...

[Did Oskar Schindler really lament not having saved more Jews?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85845/did-oskar-schindler-really-lament-not-having-saved-more-jews)

...was asked only with respect to the movie, i.e. if I hadn't seen it, or if the relevant scene hadn't been included, I wouldn't care about the answer, even if I was very interested in Oskar Schindler. I'm sure there are many similar type things about other fact-based movies (e.g. Titanic, to name one off the top of my head) that may interest people because they are fans of the movie, rather than just general historical curiosity,

So IMHO, the tag is on-topic. It sheds light on the level of research done, dramatic license taken or respect/disrespect to the truth had by the movie makers.